# general term for wheat, barley, oat, rye

Tags: hypernyms

What would you call the thing on this image:

[image: sheaves of wheat golden at harvest time]

http://www.tla.estranky.cz/img/mid/51/obili.jpg

I am looking for the general term, I know that it has more types:

- wheat
- barley
- oat
- rye

Suggestions:

- grain
- cereal
- cereals

Comment: Do you want to include rice, millet, etc.?

Comment: These would generally be referred to as *cereal grains*.

Comment: *cereals*, or *grasses*. Cereals are grasses whose seeds are starchy and used as human food.

Answer (score 10):

*Cereal* and *grain* are the go-to names for these; in Britain, they sometimes use *corn*. Since your picture shows plants growing on a field, you may choose to be more precise by calling them *cereal plants*, *cereal crops* or *grain plants*/*crops*.

From a botanical perspective, these plants are all *Poaceae* (or *Gramineae*) in taxonomic terminology, and *grasses* or *true grasses* in English.

Comment: Also fro a "botanic perspective" is [**caryopsis**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/caryopsis): *a small, one-celled, one-seeded, dry indehiscent fruit with the pericarp adherent to the seed coat, the **typical fruit of grasses and grains**.*

Comment: My understanding is that the original use of **corn** was as the term for all grain crops. When the New World was discovered and maize introduced to the English-speaking world is was called Indian corn. In the States the word 'corn' gradually came to mean maize and no other grains but in Britain we have continued to use 'corn' in its original sense.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, The King James bible from 1611 uses "corn" in this way and arguably another: "*the most popular grain of a country*".